# Why isn't Unity loading on VirtualBox?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, windows, 12.10

[image: http://puu.sh/23sZM]

I also tried [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), and none of the solutions worked. The virtual machine runs Ubuntu 12.10 i386 and the host computer has Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install 'guest additions'. Navigate to menu, under **Devices** choose **Install Guest Additions**, enter your password, wait for the script to completed, reboot your virtual machine.